# Redirect index.html from Public folder to Subfolder on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this .htaccess inside of Public_html folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Currently it is getting the index.html inside the Public_html folder but I need to redirect to index.html inside my subfolder. I tried this but it doesn´t worked:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\subfolder\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: And "doesn't work" means what actually?

Comment: What is the URL that is actually requested?

Comment: I assume the pattern in the first rule of the second code block is a "typo"?

Comment: And try replacing the "." in the last rule with a "^".

Comment: "doesn't work" means that when I access the subfolder URL the page is blank. The URL should it be mydomain/subfolder.

Comment: Is your front-controller expecting `/subfolder` to be in the URL? Note that if you are requesting `/subfolder` (no trailing slash) then Apache will actually trigger a redirect to `/subfolder/` (with a trailing slash) and your `.htaccess` is not actually being used, so this doesn't really look like a `.htaccess` problem. (Although your first `RewriteRule` is obviously wrong (a typo?), but this won't cause it to fail.) However, if `/subfolder` is part of the visible URL then it may be preferable to use a `.htaccess` file at `/subfolder/.htaccess` instead (adjusting accordingly).

Comment: "when I access the subfolder URL the page is blank" ... I fail to understand that, sorry. What _exatly_ is the "subfolder URL"? If that is a URL with "subfolder" in it, then why is that relevant here? Such a URL should never get called by a client, right? Apart from that ... it is "blank"? What _exactly_ does that mean? What does your browsers console reveal what the response actually is? Any headers? Length? Error states? What does your http server's error log file say?

Comment: The customer should access the URL like this: mydomain.com/subfolder. When I enter just the mydomain.com, the page loads correctly, but when I access the mydomain.com/subfolder is blank, the headers of the page seems normal but the page itself is blank. When I use the devtools F12 option, the div id = root got nothing to show. The subfolder should be a visible part of URL.

Comment: As mentioned above, this sounds like a fault with your front-controller (ie. `/subfolder/index.html`), not `.htaccess`.